Spring AOP injecting a 'silent' method parameter
I'm pretty sure it's not possible to achieve this strange behaviour, but going to throw it out there ..
I want to inject a method parameter and have it available to the method code. However I do not want it in the parameter list.
My current implementation is I have written an Aspect which searches for a Transaction object in the parameter list, creates and starts that transaction, injects it in the right place in the args[], proceeds(args) and then commits or rolls back. I can't use spring transactions because it's a global transaction which manages two underlying resources which do not support XA transactions and I don't want have this custom transaction management boiler plate code pasted into every method.
e.g. pseudocode of how it would be applied
@MyTransaction
public void myMethod (String user, Transaction tx, String otherParam) {
    mySPecialAdapter.insert(createSomeCypherQL(user), tx);
}

The problem is it looks weird from the calling site, like I have to pass something, even though I know under the hood it will be replaced by the correct Transaction object
myMethod("user", null, "otherParam");

Maybe I'm coming at it from the wrong angle..

Personally, I wouldn't use an aspect to do this.  Mainly because there's no way to magically inject a parameter that isn't in the method signature.  Secondly, those annotation-driven aspects will cause a lot of head scratching unless it's well documented in the java docs where the @#%@ the Transaction comes from.
This is what I would do.
First, extract the logic that resolves the Transaction from the aspect and place it into a Service
@Service
public class TransactionService {
    public Transaction resolveTransaction( /* the args that are needed */ ) {
        ...
        return transaction;
    }
}

Inject this service into the component that exposes myMethod
...

@Autowired
private TransactionService transactionService;

// delegate to the service to resolve the Transaction
public void myMethod (String user, String otherParam) {
  mySPecialAdapter.insert(createSomeCypherQL(user), transactionService.resolveTransaction(/* the args that are required */);
}


Good answer, but because it is my pet peeve, I want to remark that I am trying to avoid annotation-driven aspects, if possible. I always try to keep the core code as clean as possible and make aspect functionality independent of marker annotations, trying to match the correct joinpoints by other means like class or return types, method signatures, implemented interfaces, maybe even class or method names. The best aspect is an invisible one. That is not always possible, but often enough. Of course, you are right that AOP does not and is not supposed to magically change method signatures.

@kriegaex I'm a little confused by your comment.  This solution does not involve any aspects and it's also for the question that was asked, do you also have the same question?

I know. I was just referring to your own criticism of "annotation-driven aspects" in a broader context. AOP users might read your answer due to the tagged question, therefore I wanted to mention it. There are ways to solve this problem properly using AOP, too, just not the way the OP imagined it. But I am not going to write an answer, because your solution is good. Not everything needs to be solved by means of AOP.
